# Is there a way to check condition while streaming a list

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Persons entity and it has a field contactType.
Now according to contact type I want to map List to different resource file ie WorkContactResource or HomeContactResource.I will be using java 8.

```
workContact=personList.stream().filter(p->p.getPhoneType == PhoneType.WORK).map(WorkResource::new).collect(Collectors.toList());

homeContact=personList.stream().filter(p->p.getPhoneType == PhoneType.HOME).map(HomeResource::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

workContact.addAll(homeContact);

I made to two different List.
But what I want is while streaming personsList I would be checking if contactType is home or work and there only map to specific resource.
How to achieve this.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your desired outcome? Do you want a single `List` of both `WorkResource` and `HomeResource`, which each `Person` filtered to its respective entity based on phone type?

Comment: yes I want a single List

Comment: What is the type of the List for workContact?

Comment: With Java you cannot have more than one return value, so I suggest you forget using `stream()` and write a simple `for`-each instead. Although it's asymptotic complexity would stay the same which is `O(n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it should be something like this

```
abstract class Resource {   
}

class WorkResource extends Resource {
    public WorkResource(Person person) {
        ***********
    }
}

class HomeResource extends Resource {
    public HomeResource(Person person) {
        ***********
    }
}

Map<PhoneType, List<Resource>> contacts = personList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p->p.getPhoneType, Collectors.mapping(Resource::new)));
```

And then iterate through a map by the type

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want a single list as an output, the most neat would be probably to create a method that does that and refer to it: `.map(this::asResource)`

```
public Resource asResource(Person person) {
    if (person.getPhoneType() == PhoneType.WORK) {
        return new WorkResource(person);
    } else {
        return new HomeResource(person);
    }
}
```

That would make your code look like this:

```
personList.stream()
        .map(this::asResource)
        .collect(toList());
```

You can also declare that method in another class, as static so that the usage looks e.g. like this `PersonConverter::asResource`.